# Nested JSON PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to generate a JSON array of objects in the form of name, parent, and children from the mySQL data shown below.

[image: Sample Table from mySQL]

Ideally my output would look like:

```
[{"name":"Abbey Road","parent":"Beatles","children":[{"name":"Come Together","parent":"Abbey Road"}, {"name":"Something","parent":"Abbey Road"},{"name":"Maxwell","parent":"Abbey Road"}, {"name":"Oh! Darling","parent":"Abbey Road"}]}]
```

With the same structure for the REM album.

Right now, I am only able to get this:

```
[{"name":"Abbey Road","parent":"Beatles","children":[{"name":"Come Together","parent":"Abbey Road"}]},{"name":"Accelerate","parent":"REM","children":[{"name":"Living Well","parent":"Accelerate"}]}]
```

The structure works, but I am only returning one record from the database.

Here's my code in PHP that generates the single record return:

```
$results_select = mysql_query("SELECT album_table.album , album_table.artist, album_table.year,
tracks_table.track
FROM album_table
JOIN tracks_table ON tracks_table.album = album_table.album");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results_select)) {

            if (!isset($info[$row['album']])) {
                $info[$row['album']] = array(
                   'name' => $row['album'],
                   'parent' => $row['artist'],
                   'children' => array(['name' => $row['track'],
                                      'parent' => $row['album'] ])
          );
       }

}
$data = json_encode(array_values($info));
echo $data;
```

I feel like I am very close to a solution, if I could just return more than one record in my php code.

Thanks very much for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: Stop what you're doing, start over again. You're using database APIs that have been deprecated and unsupported for 5 years now. Alternatives have been available for a decade. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: In addition, the code you show does not result in the output you claim you're getting. Your code generates an associative array which would end up as a JSON object, not a JSON array.

Comment: Hi @tomish did you solved this problem? I got same with you with my DB, only one children record show

Answer (score 0):

```
$familys = []
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results_select)) {

if (!isset($info[$row['album']]))
  $familys[ $row['album'] ][ $row['artist'] ][] = ['name' => $row['track'], 'parent' => $row['album'] ];   
}

//I think the familys is ok, if you want to make you info format: uncomment below code
/*
foreach($familys as $album => $family)
{
  foreach($family as $parent => $children)
  {
     $info[$album] = array(
                   'name' => $album,
                   'parent' => $parent,
                   'children' => $children
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks, I gave this a shot with some light editing:

Comment: but was still unable to get it to work, I end up with

Comment: [{"Abbey Road":[{"name":"Come Together","parent":"Beatles"},{"name":"Something","parent":"Beatles"},{"name":"Maxwell","parent":"Beatles"},{"name":"Oh! Darling","parent":"Beatles"}]},{"Accelerate":[{"name":"Living Well","parent":"REM"},{"name":"Man-Sized ","parent":"REM"},{"name":"Supernatural","parent":"REM"},{"name":"Hollow Man","parent":"REM"}]}]

Comment: is there any error, from the outpu row artist not work, var dump row

Comment: array(2) { ["Beatles"]=> array(1) { ["Abbey Road"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(13) "Come Together" ["parent"]=> string(7) "Beatles" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Something" ["parent"]=> string(7) "Beatles" }   -- partial dump

Comment: just change familys index, I'm confuse here why familys first index is not album but parent? are you sure there is not an error in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your database code, I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

With every loop of your code you were rewriting the array instead of adding to it with the `$array[]` construct. This should work, might require some tweaking.

```
<?php
$dsn    = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8";
$db     = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$sql    = "SELECT album_table.album, artist, year, track FROM album_table LEFT JOIN tracks_table USING (album)";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (!isset($info[$row["album"]])) {
        $info[$row["album"]] = [
            "name"     => $row["album"],
            "parent"   => $row["artist"],
            "children" => [],
        ];
    }
    $info[$row["album"]]["children"][] = [
        "name"   => $row["track"],
        "parent" => $row["album"],
    ];
}

$data = array_values($info);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Including a value from a parent node in the child seems redundant. BTW, what do you do when two artists put out an album with the same name?